# PowerShell string replace using RegEx

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

This is rather a RegEx question than PS one. Here it goes:

I have a text file with data like below.

```
ABC Corp, x567 
xyz Corp, y567 
pqr Corp, m567 
ghysds ,inc, x567 
TRWsdsdsds ,org, y567 
TYUds ,ing, m567
```

How can I remove the first comma from line 4-6? (These lines have 2 commas. I need only the second one.) My plan is to insert this data into a table with 2 columns.

Thank you.

Comment: you could try this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63ace2a7-91f0-447d-ba33-bb526518564e/powershell-regular-expressions-replace-operator-disable-the-default-global-option?forum=ITCG):  The second Answer is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use look ahead to check to see if there is a second comma on the line.

```
,(?=.*,)
```

Use this to replace whatever it matches with an empty string. This will get rid of the first comma of lines that have two commas in them.

Comment: This is the most elegant way.

Comment: Thank you Kabb! Very nice answer. Unfortunately, being a newbie, I cannot promote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:

```
$text = 
(@'
ABC Corp, x567
xyz Corp, y567 
pqr Corp, m567 
ghysds ,inc, x567 
TRWsdsdsds ,org, y567 
TYUds ,ing, m567
'@).split("`n")

$text -replace '(.+?),(.+?),(.+)','$1$2,$3'

ABC Corp, x567
xyz Corp, y567 
pqr Corp, m567 
ghysds inc, x567 
TRWsdsdsds org, y567 
TYUds ing, m567
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regular expressions for this, although it would work.

```
$StringList = @('abd,asdc,asdc', 'asdc,awegwe,aweg', 'asdfasdf,asdaweg');

foreach ($String in $StringList) {
    if ($String -match '.*,.*,') {
        $String.Remove($String.IndexOf(','), 1);
    }
    else {
        $String;
    }
}
```